Combine event binding and dynamic outputs in shiny
My Shiny app consists of selecting a set of parameters to generate outputs based on the corresponding data, where each parameter is dependent on the previous one to narrow down which data needs to be used. To achieve this I use dynamic inputs with uiOutput and renderUi.
An example of the logic would be:

Static selection of parameter 1 (choices are known)
Render dynamic selection of parameter 2 based on param1's value
Render dynamic selection of parameter 3 based on param1 and param2's values
Fetch unique report corresponding to parameters 1,2,3 selections, process data and store in reactive variable
Output renders from reactive data

On initialization, a valid set of parameters and the output reports are rendered. However I'd like to add a "Run" button so that the outputs are only rendered when the user completed their selections and manually trigger a recalculation - but the outputs still need to be rendered on initialization.
Here is a minimal reprex I put together with one static selection and one dynamic selection:
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

(homes <- tibble(
  zone = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3),
  owner = paste0("person", c(1,2,3,4,3,1)),
  price = 111000*(1:6)
))

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  selectInput("sel1", "zone", choices = unique(homes$zone)),
  uiOutput("ui_sel2"),
  actionButton("confirm", "confirm"),
  verbatimTextOutput("txt")
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {
  # render dynamic input
  output$ui_sel2 <- renderUI({
    choices <- dplyr::filter(homes, zone == input$sel1)$owner %>% unique()
    selectInput("sel2", "owner", choices = choices)
  })
  
  sel_price <- reactive({
    # need dynamic input to render before calc
    req(input$sel2)
    # get price
    dplyr::filter(homes, zone == input$sel1, owner == input$sel2)$price[1]
  })
  
  # render price from selected zone+owner
  output$txt <- renderText({paste("Price of selected home is", sel_price())}) %>%
    bindEvent(input$confirm, ignoreNULL=FALSE)
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

I tried multiple variations of bindEvent(), both on the render function and the reactive expression, trying to include both input$sel2 and input$confirm but wasn't able to achive the render on initialization. The render only works after first clicking the button, after which I get the expected behavior.
I believe it has to do with the req(input$sel2) I use in my reactive expression to ignore the dynamic until it is rendered, but I would have guessed that adding it in bindEvent() would have solved the issue - not the case.

As you already noticed, the req(input$sel2) blocks the calculation because it is null when it is first accessed. However, if the input wouldn't be null, then it would be the first choice of the rendered selectInput. So what you could do is to drop the req and replace the owner == input$sel2 inside the reactive e.g. with owner == dplyr::coalesce(input$sel2, "person1") (where the "person1" could be calculated dynamically as in the renderUI). This would yield the same functionality. Does this yield what you need? If not, what is missing?

+1 for @Jan's suggestion.  Also, you probably don't need your renderUIs.  Unless I am also missing something, you can use updateSelectInput inside an observeEvent that watches input$sel1 to update the choices for sel2 every time sel1's selection changes.

@Jan This yields what I need but only works if the values of owner are known in advance. In my case, I'd be pulling records without knowing the data in advance, and using my example "person1" wouldn't be guaranteed to exist in the subset of homes in zone A - thus making the zone & owner selection non existent in my dataset. Also, I used one dynamic input in my reprex to make it simple but have around 7 in my actual code.

@Limey I've tried to use the update functions, however choices are still initialized as NULL, so I encounter the same problem. In one case it is NULL as not rendered yet and in the other case, because of the initial value (can't get any other initial values for reasons outlined in above comment).

I would add a reactive which returns the filtered choices for the dynamic selectInput and in your sel_prices use coalesce to set it to the first element of this list in case it is NULL (so basiclaly on startup):
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

homes <- tibble(
  zone = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3),
  owner = paste0("person", c(1,2,3,4,3,1)),
  price = 111000*(1:6)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("sel1", "zone", choices = unique(homes$zone)),
  uiOutput("ui_sel2"),
  actionButton("confirm", "confirm"),
  verbatimTextOutput("txt")
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {
  get_choices <- reactive({
    dplyr::filter(homes, zone == input$sel1) %>% 
      pull(owner) %>% 
      unique()
  })
  
  output$ui_sel2 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("sel2", "owner", choices = get_choices())
  })
  
  sel_price <- reactive({
    filter(homes, zone == input$sel1, 
                  owner == coalesce(input$sel2, get_choices()[[1L]])) %>% 
      pull(price)
  })

  output$txt <- renderText({
    paste("Price of selected home is", sel_price())
  }) %>%
    bindEvent(input$confirm, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

